# Filtering by a coalesced LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a MySQL query I'm trying to optimize, that has to do with permissions. Here's a simplified version:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photo
    LEFT JOIN photo_access ON viewer=4 AND owner=photo.photographer
WHERE
    photo.album = 10
AND NOT photo.hidden
AND COALESCE(photo_access.access, 3) >= photo.privacy; -- 3=default access
```

For our purposes, here's the columns we care about, for each table.

```
photo.photographer : User ID of who took the photo
photo.album        : Album ID (photo can only belong to one album)
photo.hidden       : Tombstone value for photos that were removed by moderators
photo.privacy      : Int, higher values = more restricted, 1=public 8=just_me
photo_access.viewer : Who is making the web request
photo_access.owner  : Who owns the content
photo_access.access : Value like photo.privacy
```

Most users have a default access level (3) to other users' content. We store deviations from that default (because of friendship or blocking people etc.) in the `photo_access` table. You can think of this as an override to the access=3 default, for a given pair of viewer and content owner.

Now assume there's a couple million users. To actually store all possible pairings would be N<sup>2</sup> rows, which is a bit crazy. I considered storing default pairs for simplicity, but it's just not reasonable at this scale.

For some values and situations, this setup works great. But to throw out some scale numbers, to get on the same brainwave as the query optimizer's cardinality estimator, let's say there's:

- 500 albums in the database,
- 1 million photos in total,
- 80K photos in a particular fairly large album (id=10),
- of which, 70K have `NOT photo.hidden`.

To my gut, I'd think it makes sense to filter first on album/hidden, then by privacy. But when I `EXPLAIN` the query, it:

- uses a `(album, hidden, photographer)` index on `photo`,
- Only uses the first two fields (ignoring photagrapher), as `const, const`,
- But estimates it'll have to look at 150K rows! That's almost double the album size, and more than double the visible photos - given the index being used, I'd expect something much closer to 70K here.
- The Extra column is NULL. Not usually a good sign.

And this query is not an asynchronous report. It runs in about 0.50s, when it should run in the 0.01-0.06s range. This also makes me wary about building temporary tables.

Is there something I'm missing here? Are these filter criteria (album vs. the photographer-based photo_access join) at impossible cross-purposes? Even an (accurate!) mark-as-duplicate would point me in the right direction.

Comment: Shouldn't `viewer=4` be moved from `ON` to `WHERE`?  `ON` should specify how the two tables are related; `WHERE` provides filtering.

Comment: What table(s) are `owner` and `viewer` in?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe splitting of your select to the union of two selects could help? Something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT 1 as `dummy` FROM photo
        INNER JOIN photo_access ON viewer=4 AND owner=photo.photographer
    WHERE
        photo.album = 10
    AND NOT photo.hidden
    AND photo_access.access >= photo.privacy
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 as `dummy` FROM photo
        LEFT JOIN photo_access ON viewer=4 AND owner=photo.photographer
    WHERE
        photo.album = 10
    AND NOT photo.hidden
    AND photo_access.access is null)
```

Comment: That's a great idea, I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: This does help clarify where the problem lives. If I run each query separately, I see that the INNER JOIN query is quite fast, but the LEFT JOIN query is slow.

I did make a few changes trying to optimize it. I tried using an EXISTS subquery. When that didn't work, I updated the index to be `(album, hidden, privacy)`, which gave a much better EXPLAIN but the results were still slow.

Comment: With the updated index:

The left join approach now has "Using index condition" for `photo` and "Using where" for `photo_access`. It's looking at ~150K photo rows still.

The subquery approach has the same row count, but it has "Using index condition; Using where" for `photo` and "Using index" for `photo_access`.

Comment: Also maybe joining with subquery `select photographer from photo where photo.album = 10` could help?

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement on Alexsey's solution:

```
SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... ) +
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... )
    FROM DUAL
```

`SELECT COUNT(*) ...` is less work (a single row) than building a table of 1's via `SELECT 1 ...`

The `FROM DUAL` may not be necessary.